# "Where" to secure a JBoss7 + Apache2 web application

Tags: apache, ssl, https, jboss

I have a question about using HTTPS in a JBossAS7 web application (a "universal" shopping cart system) exposed **via AJP (tomcat) connector** with an Apache2 web server.

I read some documentation on how to configure SSL-HTTPS in JBossAS and a lot of tutorials explaining SSL with Apache2 but....

Which way do I have to choose?
Is it enough to configure SSL-HTTPS in Apache2 for my website/application?

Or do I have to configure JBoss for SSL too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think configuring SSL on both JBoss and Apache is an overkill.  I suggest you implement SSL on Apache only.  You could add an additional layer of security by adding firewall rules to only allow Apache web servers to access JBoss application servers.